# Error with PHP script when using Android application on my own device

Tags: php, android, mysql

In my application, I use a database (WAMP server) and PHP script to connect it with my application. But the problem is when I run it with Android emulator. It's working but when I use my application on device, it does not work.

The error is:

> " java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 80):
>   connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)"

Comment: Your application on your device cannot connect to your WAMP server. Have you checked the IP settings in your application?

Comment: I don't know how to do on android studio

Answer (score 0):

Your web server could be accessed by the emulator using a special alias to your host loopback interface (10.0.2.2). If you're using WiFi on your actual device, you will need to specify the local IP address of your web server (on most home networks it's going to be 192.168.x.x). Over cellular, you would have to have some port forwards setup on your router and to use the external IP address / domain name of your web server.

Comment: I tried to call my script like that :  String login_url = "http://192.168.72.1/log.php"; but doesn't work

Comment: You have to specify the protocol too. So add 'http://' before it. And that is of?

Comment: @baudic_j On a separate computer, or using a web browser on your phone over WiFi, you are able to visit that webpage (or any other webpage on that web server)? This could also be a software / Windows firewall issue not allowing requests over port 80.

Comment: @baudic_j Ok so this is a firewall issue, make sure you add exceptions for inbound port 80 to your web server and verify you have the IP address of your web server correct (using ipconfig from the cmd prompt). The answer here should work for you: http://superuser.com/questions/432794/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-my-wamp-server

Comment: @baudic_j Let me know how you've made out.

Comment: @baudic_j I've got one last thing for you to try - completely disable / turn off the Windows Firewall and any AntiVirus software you have (just temporarily while you test). If this works, you can turn things back on one at a time and see what's blocking the connections and make exceptions as needed. Best of luck.